# How can I pass data to a table in linkki-framework?

Tags: java, linkki

I want to create a table with the [linkki framework](https://github.com/linkki-framework/linkki) in my application. I know that I can use the ContainerPmo class to define a table, but how can I pass data to be shown as rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you have a classic linkki setup with UI <-> PMO <-> DomainModel, it is easier to use the [`SimpleTablePmo`](http://doc.linkki-framework.org/linkki-0.9.20180118/05_ui_components/04_tables.html#ui-simple-table-pmo) instead of ContainerPmo. It wraps the ItemSupplier so that you only have to call the super constructor and implement one method.

If you choose to use the `SimpleTablePmo`, you can just pass the list of domain model object to the constructor of your implementation of `SimpleTablePmo`. If the content of the list will change while you display the table consider to use a `Supplier<List<DMO>>` instead of simply providing a list.

For every domain model object in the list, a new presentation model object (PMO) is created with `createRow(...)`. Hence this method also has to be implemented. In most cases this method is as simple as

```
protected AnyPmo createRow(AnyDmo m) {
    return new AnyPmo(m);
}
```

On every UI update the binding will check the list of model elements (in second case calls the supplier to get the list). If the list is unchanged (equal objects are still present in the same order) the binding only updates the content of the existing fields. If the list is changed it will remove all rows and use createRow` to create new pmos.